# I'm stuck at turning an array into an array of objects issue

Tags: javascript

So my array looks like this:

```
var data = ["5/10/2014", 2, "5/10/2014", 5, "5/11/2014", 6....];
```

The array has over a thousands cells, which really doesn't matter but I'll mention it anyways.

I want to turn that array into an array of objects that look like this:

```
var iWantToBelieve = [{Date:"5/10/2014", Score: 2}, {Date: 5/10/2014, Score:5}.....];
```

I feel like I'm close to solving the problem but my code gives me the end result of this:

```
 var iWantToBelieve = [{Date:"5/10/2014", Score: "5/10/2014"}, {Date: 5/10/2014, Score: "5/10/2014"}.....]
```

My code looks like this:

```
 var data = ["5/10/2014", 2, "5/10/2014", 5, "5/11/2014", 6....];
 var init = [];
 var tempObject;

 for(var z = 0; z < data.length; z++){

     var tempArray = ["Date", "Score"];
     tempObject = {};

     for(var y = 0; y < tempArray.length; y++){
         tempObject[tempArray[y]] = data[z];
     }

     init.push(tempObject);
 }
```

I know that the second for loop finishes the 2 iterations before the first loop can start another iteration, so both the Date and the Score keys are all occupied by the date string.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use for and increment the itterator by 2.

```js
var iWantToBelieve = []
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) { // i = 0, 2, 4..
  iWantToBelieve.push({
      Date: data[i], // 1st value is the date
      Score: data[i + 1] // 2nd value is score
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast and correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = ["5/10/2014", 2, "5/10/2014", 5, "5/11/2014", 6]
var result = []

for (var j=0; j<data.length; j+=2)
  result.push({ Date: data[j], Score: data[j + 1]})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = ["5/10/2014", 2, "5/10/2014", 5, "5/11/2014", 6];
var result = [];
while (data.length) result.push({Date: data.shift(), Score: data.shift()});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You would get better results and more points if you added an explanation of what you are doing or what is going on.